# How to Run Two Slow SQL SELECT Statements Simultaneously

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In SQL, is there any way to run multiple SELECT statements simultaneously, then join the results?  Most examples that I've seen on the internet seem to involve the SELECT statements being run in sequential fashion, followed by JOINs and other statements.

An example of the code would look something like this:

```
SELECT x, y FROM Table apples WHERE ... as t1
left join
    (SELECT x, y FROM Table oranges WHERE ... as t2)
on
     t1.x = t2.x
```

Now imagine that `SELECT x, y FROM Table apples WHERE ... as t1`  takes a long time.  How can I run both SELECT statements above simultaneously (similar to threaded calls in say Java or C#, for example) to save time?  Or does Oracle already do this?

Cheers

Comment: How about keeping another table that stores a `ks` + corresponding count and maintain it with triggers?

Comment: Interesting.  What would the SQL for that look like?  Sorry, my SQL experience is limited.

Comment: Btw, `SUM(WHEN Age > Palt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Sorry guys, I think the syntax of the original example drew away from my main question, which was simultaneous SELECT statement execution, so I've changed the example.  Apologies.  I've upvoted those that answered the earlier example.

Comment: "which was simultaneous SELECT statement execution" --- the general solution is to rewrite a query in a way so that you did not need that

Comment: Yes, and perhaps even design the db in a better manner.  Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Oracle does not perform them at the same time. The closest that it comes to that is parallel query, in which stages of a single query can be apportioned across multiple parallel query sessions automatically and the results combined by a query coordinator session.

You might try combining the logic of multiple queries into one (as zerkms suggests) and optimising the query to use covering indexes (for example) -- in other words, standard approaches for a slow-performing query.

One of the potentially fatal problems with combining the results of separately executed queries is that they are not consistent. Each one would generally have a slightly different point of time for which it is looking for consistent data, unless you used flashback query to get slightly old results.

If the data is static then you could use DBMS_Scheduler to run multiple queries at the same time that load to a common table, and then select from there. DBMS_Scheduler can define chains of processes which can execute in series, or in parallel, and offers very sophisticated end condition checking on what steps should execute when. It's a big hammer to apply though, and is normally used for batch processing (eg data warehouse ELT processes).

Comment: "is that they are not consistent" - what about transactions?

Comment: In Oracle terms you get two queries to see the same consistency point by using a transaction in serializable read consistency mode, but you're looking for two queries to be executed using two different processes -- they cannot share the same transaction.

Comment: it makes sense, didn't think about it from such angle

Comment: If the data is known to be static then of course it's a moot point.

Comment: I think both zerkms and yourself gave excellent answers, so thank you.  Hard to pick the "best" answer here.

Answer (score 3):

It can be all done in a single query without joins or subqueries:

```
  SELECT ks,
         COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks',
         SUM(CASE WHEN Age > Palt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '# Late'
    FROM Table
GROUP BY ks
```

As a possible performance improvement it worth trying to create a composite `(ks, Age, Palt)` index

Comment: It's true that in this situation a query optimisation might be successful, but I don't feel that it answers the core question.

Comment: @David Aldridge: it depends. It's frequent that people try to solve the issue the wrong way (due to lack of experience or knowledge or whatever). So the final solution would be not a straight answer for the question asked, but something that would just solve the original task in more efficient/best practice method.

Comment: I'm all in favour of finding more simple solutions, especially when performance is at the root of the issue -- my first choice would always be to optimise the query, and the method you show is what I'd try in this case (I think you'd need a CASE keyword in there though?). The question itself raises interesting architectural issues however, particularly for non-DB experts.

Comment: @David Aldridge: indeed, that's why I +1'd you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 12c allows the [concurrent execution of union all](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17613/parallel003.htm#VLDBG14131).  That still won't run *every* step of the execution plan in parallel, but it can come much closer.

However, that feature is almost never needed.  Regular parallel query is capable of using all available system resources for a single query.

If APPLES and ORANGES are large enough, there's plenty of work to divide for each table.  And some operations, such as sorting and hashing, will be done concurrently.  That's why Oracle sometimes allocates twice as many parallel servers as the requested degree of parallelism.

If APPLES and ORANGES are small, the database has to worry about running many queries at the same time.  It's not worth starting and coordinating multiple threads for something that doesn't take very long.